# How to get method return type in typescript

Tags: angular, typescript

I am new to typescript and stuck in the following code.
Here is my code

```
private basketSource = new BehaviorSubject<IBasket>(null);

    getCurrentBasketValue(): IBasket {
        return this.basketSource.value;  
      }
```

and I want to get its value in return type ' IBasket ' in a basket variable. see below

```
const basket = this.getCurrentBasketValue;
```

but it returns the type ' () => IBasket '.

Note: IBasket is an interface

Please help me what should I do? I will be grateful if someone solve this problem.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: try `return this.basketSource.getValue()` instead of `return this.basketSource.value` and remove `(null)`;

Comment: @MarcusCantu thank you for your time and help. Luckily I have find my mistake that is when I'm calling the this.getCurrentBasketValue() method, I forget to add () in call i.e. I'm calling this.getCurrentBasketValue which is wrong and causing the issue. But I'm surprised why TypeScript did not raised it as an error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are creating a constant with a reference to your function:

```
const basket = this.getCurrentBasketValue;
```

If you want to get the value, you need to call the function:

```
const basket = this.getCurrentBasketValue();
```